# Attaching onclick to img elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
function prepareEventHandlers() {    
    var myImga = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    myImga.onclick = function () {
        alert("This is Eminem Known As RAP God. The Best Rapper ever");
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}
```

why this  function is not running in JavaScript.

Comment: `myImga` is a DOM Collection (a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)), not a single Element. In any case make sure to be precise: "function is not running" could mean a number of things given the above context.

Comment: Getelementsbytagname returns an array of elements,  you can't just add an onclick handler to it

Comment: Loop through the collection and attach the event handler individually.

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < myImga.length; i++) { myImga[i].onclick = function() {...}; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Modify `myImga.onclick` to `myImga[0].onclick`. It will work for first element..

Comment: Make sure to also explain *why* said change is required. (Also, this will fail when there are 0 images, or 2 or more images that should have the event bound.)

Comment: because document.getElementByTagName returns array of elements... if there is no img it returns blank array i.e. []. If array is blank then passing index 0 will not work.. and if you want to bind click event to all the img then you need to loop through the array..

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not make much sense, but however by using jquery you can acheive that quite easy.

The problem is that you are fetching an array of elements, native javascript does not support setting click events on an array of elements. Also if there is no img on the page your code will fail and break other javascript code further down in the code. If you on the other hand uses jquery and on click events you it will check that for you and make the click accessable if the image is loaded after the javascript has been loaded.

Hope this helps

first include jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can simply add this to your page

```
<script>    
     $('img').on(document, 'click', 
        function() {
           alert("This is Eminem Known As RAP God. The Best Rapper ever");
        }
     );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a for loop to loop over the objects that are returned:

```
function myAlert(){
        alert("You clicked the picture. Good for you.");
}

function prepareEventHandlers() {    
    var myImga = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    for(var i=0,l=myImga.length; i<l; ++i) myImga[i].onclick = myAlert;
}

window.onload = function () {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}
```

It is possible, and perhaps worthwhile, to test this in a browser.  Use control-shift-J brings up developer tools in chrome -- you can even try this from Stackoverflow -- and then type:

`myImga = document.getElementsByTagName('img')`

and you will immediately see that myImga is an array.

The for line works in the browser developer tools as well if you use an anonymous function to set the alert.  Happy alerting.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
<script>
function prepareEventHandlers() {    
    var myImga = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(x in myImga){
    myImga[x].onclick = function () {
        alert("This is Eminem Known As RAP God. The Best Rapper ever");
    }
}
}

window.onload = function () {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}
</script>
```